# exchangeratesapi.io request giving me undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to make a currency converter, but the API call doesn't seem to be recognizing my second input. It does, however, recognize the first input which is why I'm so confused.

In my Ajax request when I console.log(data.rates.EUR) it gives me what I want. I can also console.log(currency2) and I get the string "EUR" (or whatever my currency2 is set to depending on the value of the input). However, it doesn't recognize currency2 and console.log's undefined when I try to run (data.rates.currency2). I'm kind of a beginner and I feel this may have to do with asynchronous or something. I would greatly appreciate any help as I've been stumped on this all day.

Thanks!

```
HTML
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">
<select class="form-control" name="" id="curr1">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="GBP">GBP</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="from">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">
<select class="form-control" name="" id="curr2">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="GBP">GBP</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-8">
<input type="none" class="form-control" id="to">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-12 text-center">
<button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>



JS

$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
convert();
});

function convert(){
let currency1 = $('#curr1').val();
let currency2 = $('#curr2').val();


$.ajax("https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?base=" + currency1 
).done(function(data){
console.log(currency2);
console.log(data.rates.EUR);
console.log(data.rates.currency2);
});

}
```

Comment: input type="none" isn't a thing. It also needs a name, as do your select.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `currency2` related value from response with just indexer `data.rates[currency2]`.

```js
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
convert();
});

function convert(){
let currency1 = $('#curr1').val();
let currency2 = $('#curr2').val();


$.ajax("https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?base=" + currency1 
).done(function(data){ 
  var val = parseFloat($("#from").val());
  $("#to").val(val ? val * data.rates[currency2] : 0)
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">
<select class="form-control" name="" id="curr1">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="GBP">GBP</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="from">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">
<select class="form-control" name="" id="curr2">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="GBP">GBP</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="to">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-12 text-center">
<button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
</div>
```